# How to use more than one jQuery AutoSuggest on a single page?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

Thanks for your reply. so i was not adding more details abt my prob. now i am explaining the whole  issue..

I Created one Autosuggest in my page and now i want another two autosuggests in the same page meaning total of three autosuggests in a page.

i used this syntaxt for creating autosuggest in my page.

```
$("input[type=text]").autoSuggest("http://mysite.com/path/to/script", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});
```

but if i will put another two autosuggest in a page then i an getting only first autosuggest value. means i dont know what to put in jquery and what to put in HTML.

Can you please give me some simple example to create three autosuggest in a single page..

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="first" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="text" id="third" />


$("#first").autoSuggest("http://mysite.com/path/to/script/first", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});

$("#second").autoSuggest("http://mysite.com/path/to/script/second", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});

$("#third").autoSuggest("http://mysite.com/path/to/script/third", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});
```

Comment: ya thanks for your reply but how to retrive that autosuggest value...?